# Yahoo finance API stock past values

Tags: c#, yahoo-finance

I'd like to get past values of stocks using the Yahoo finance API.
I found this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37550/Stock-quote-and-chart-from-Yahoo-in-C
but I can only get the stock's latest value.
Does anybody know if it is even possible to get a stock's value by date using this API (or any other)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the YQL Api for Yahoo Finance, see [here](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2009/06/02/getting-stock-information-with-yql-and-open-data-tables/).

The url to query is the following:
    `"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22"+symbol+"%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%22"+ startDate +"%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%22"+ endDate +"%22"+ dataFormat`

where:
 - `symbol` is the list of tickers, for example 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'YHOO'
 - `startDate` is the first day of quotations
 - `endDate` is the final day of quotations
 - `dataFormat` is the following string:

`&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys`

The result is a XML file you can fetch to retrieve historical values.
I advise you to use the [YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env) a lot in the beginning to create the exact request you want.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using the YAHOO! api.
http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvHistQuotesDownload